# My ubuntu server is losing connectivity, require assistance troubleshooting

Tags: ubuntu-10.04

I have two server monitoring tools that check the uptime of my Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS server. Over the last month both of these tools have reported the following outages:

- Jan - 15mins: self recovery
- Jan - 5 mins: self recovery
- Feb - 15mins: I managed to be online when this happened and logged into my control panel to find that my server was shutdown. I manually restarted it only because I was online. I wonder if it would have restarted?

I have contacted my VPS provider (webbynode) who could not see any any problems with their VPS infrastructure for the February outage.

I have also checked the following log files to see if there are any anomalies that could be the cause of the outages; I am unable to see anything related to the server shutdown (Feb) in these logs:

- /var/log/auth.log
- /var/log/apache2/error.log
- /var/log/syslog
- /var/log/kern.log
- /var/log/boot
- /var/log/messages

Could anyone suggest any other things I should look out for, such as additional system logs?

I just added bootlogging through /etc/default/bootlogd

Comment: By seeing it in your control panel I am guessing that the actural server is shutting down and not apache... could you just put some light on that please :)

Comment: Errr, I am not sure why it shutdown, but that is the extact purpose of this post!  :)

Answer (score 0):

It would be a good idea to check out the /var/log/messages log and you could tail it, this shuld hhopefully increase your chances of finding the issue

Comment: Just checked the messages log and it has no events before the server restarted. Then it displays the server restart information.